# Non degenerate upper triangular matricies 2

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set V of upper-triangular n×n matrices with elements in some ﬁeld K. I.e., if A is such a matrix, aij=0, for i>j
Show that non-degenerate upper-triangular matrices form a group with respect to matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

To show that the set of non-singular upper-triangular matrices form a group under multiplication (or for that matter, than any set under any binary operation is a group), you need to check four things:

1. Multiplication is associative. This can probably be taken for granted since matrix multiplication in general is associative.
2. The set of non-singular upper triangular matrices is closed under multiplication. That is, that if you take two such matrices and multiply them, you still end up with a non-singular upper-triangular matrix.
3. The set includes the identity matrix.
4. For any non-singular upper triangular matrix, its inverse is also upper triangular (and non-singular).

Check these, one at a time, and you're done.

Comment: how can i check these for a general matrix aij?

Comment: Can I ask what is a **degenerate** upper triangular matrix?

Comment: @narip "Degenerate matrix" is a somewhat common synonym for "singular matrix".